# Software center is broken -f install doesn't work

Tags: 14.10, dependencies

When I use `sudo apt-get -f install` in terminal, the following happens:

```
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 237694 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../linux-tools-3.16.0-31_3.16.0-31.41_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking linux-tools-3.16.0-31 (3.16.0-31.41) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-3.16.0-31_3.16.0-31.41_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite '/usr/lib/libcpupower.so.3.16.0-31', which is also in package linux-lts-utopic-tools-3.16.0-31 3.16.0-31.41~14.04.1
dpkg-deb: error: subprocess paste was killed by signal (Broken pipe)
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/linux-tools-3.16.0-31_3.16.0-31.41_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running 14.10, you should not have linux-lts-utopic-tools-3.16.0-31. Where did you get that anyway?

Lesson one: use your package manager.

Unlike windows, where you search for and download exe files to install programs or applications, in linux you use the package manager (apt-get).

Open a terminal and execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get purge linux-lts-utopic-tools-3.16.0-31 linux-tools-3.16.0-31
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic
```

If you need to search for software to install, use the synaptic-package-manager

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

to run synaptic:

```
sudo synaptic
```

to do a command line search for available software:

```
apt-cache search linux-tools
```

to narrow the search use grep:

```
apt-cache search linux-tools | grep tools
```

to uninstall software, use apt-get purge:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-tools-generic
```

to install, use apt-get install:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic
```

to reinstall, use apt-get install --reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall linux-tools-generic
```

to install basic updates

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

to install system updates

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the problematic package

`sudo apt-get remove linux-tools-3.16.0-31`

then fix the packages

`sudo apt-get -f`

and then install it again

`sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install linux-tools-generic`